# Sequential or dynamic multidimensional scaling

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling

I am looking for a way to conduct sequential (dynamic) MDS based on several variables coded for a sequence of stimuli. Could anyone direct me to software for this purpose (especially R packages / code)?